# ReactJS API authentication : Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, api

I am building an app with ReactJS that authenticate users through a Laravel API.
This is a very simple app. And the authentication part is working well. But after authentication when I try to change the state I am getting this error.

```
Cannot update during an existing state transition
```

The App I am trying to build is a very simple one. After the app makes an API call to authenticate the user, it must get the user's data from the API response and pass those responses to the component set for logged in users.

I  made some search on the error `Cannot update during an existing state transition`. All the answers I am getting are telling me not to setState inside of a render. I am not doing that.
Here is my code

App.jsx

```
//...

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user: {}
        };
    }

    _loginUser = (email, password) => {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("email", email);
        formData.append("password", password);

        axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/api/user/login", formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
            .then(json => {
                if (json.data.success) {
                    let userData = {
                        first_name: json.data.data.first_name,
                        name: json.data.data.name,
                        id: json.data.data.email,
                        email: json.data.data.email,
                        auth_token: json.data.data.auth_token,
                        timestamp: new Date().toString()
                    };
                    let appState = {
                        isLoggedIn: true,
                        user: userData
                    };
                    //Save app state with user date in local storage
                    localStorage["appState"] = JSON.stringify(appState);
                    this.setState({
                        isLoggedIn: appState.isLoggedIn,
                        user: appState.user
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#feedbacks").html(
                        `<span className="alert alert-danger">Login Failed: ${
                            json.data.data
                        }</span>`
                    );
                }

                $("#email-login-btn")
                    .removeAttr("disabled")
                    .html("Login");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                $("#feedbacks").html(
                    `<span className="alert alert-danger">An Error Occured</span>`
                );
                $("#email-login-btn")
                    .removeAttr("disabled")
                    .html("Login");
            });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let state = localStorage["appState"];
        if (state) {
            let AppState = JSON.parse(state);
            console.log(AppState);
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: AppState.isLoggedIn,
                user: AppState
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (
            !this.state.isLoggedIn &&
            this.props.location.pathname !== "/app/login"
        ) {
            this.props.history.push("/app/login");
        }
        if (
            this.state.isLoggedIn &&
            (this.props.location.pathname === "/app/login" ||
                this.props.location.pathname === "/app/register")
        ) {
            this.props.history.push("/");
        }
        return (
            <Switch data="data">
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/"
                    render={props => (
                        <Home
                            {...props}
                            logOut={this._logoutUser}
                            isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
                            user={this.state.user}
                        />
                    )}
                />

                <Route
                    path="/app/login"
                    render={props => (
                        <Login {...props} loginUser={this._loginUser} />
                    )}
                />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

const AppContainer = withRouter(props => <App {...props} />);
render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>,

    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Login.jsx

```
const Login = ({ history, loginUser = f => f }) => {
    console.log(history);

    let _email, _password;
    const handleLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginUser(_email.value, _password.value);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="wrapper" className="formWrapper">

                <form method="post" action="#" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                    <div className="fields">
                        <div className="field">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Your Email</label>
                            <input
                                ref={input => (_email = input)}
                                autoComplete="off"
                                id="email"
                                name="email"
                                type="text"
                                className="center-block"
                                placeholder="email"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="field">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Your Password</label>
                            <input
                                ref={input => (_password = input)}
                                autoComplete="off"
                                id="password-input"
                                name="password"
                                type="password"
                                className="center-block"
                                placeholder="password"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="actions login">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="primary"
                            id="email-login-btn"
                        >
                            <span className="icon fa-user" /> Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="blur" />
            <div id="bg" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

The _login method handles the form submit. And within that method, I setState the user once authentication is valid. Apparently, that is where the error is coming from. That generates the error :
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
So I need to know where is the right place to change the value of the state 'user'.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Please don't use jquery with react. React is there for you to handle everything related to dom changes. You shouldn't manipulate dom directly as in loginUser method

Comment: Ok @DoğancanArabacı I will follow you instructions. Thank You. Now is there a chance that is causing the error.